# Using Google Code Prettify CDN with a custom skin

Tags: css, google-code-prettify

I'm using the Google Code Prettify CDN link:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

By design, it appends a CSS stylesheet into the DOM:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/prettify.css">
```

This is great if you want to use the default skin (or one of the URL parameter-defined skins the project makes available), but in my case, I want to use a custom theme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-custom-theme-that-is-awesome.css">
```

Uh oh, GCP appended its theme *after* mine, so now all of my styles are getting overwritten.

Is there a way to use the GCP CDN (or *a* CDN) **and** a custom stylesheet without having to add `!important` to every style in the sheet? Or am I stuck downloading GCP and including it locally in my project?

Comment: [take a look at](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md#serving-your-own-js--css)

Comment: Yep, that's where it shows how to use the auto loader - not a custom stylesheet (without downloading)

Comment: the idea was to use the load event for adding your stylesheet after the one coming in through CDN, but it's just a suggestion

Comment: Yeah I did that - it only seems to style the elements after loading not append the stylesheet after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the non-autoloader version, i.e.
https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/prettify.js

And execute PR.prettyPrint() when the page is ready. No stylesheet will be downloaded.